# Make a new column using values from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which I have created using a union all from two tables. I am trying to insert a new column in the new table created using a case statement. My requirement is if the addresses of the new table matches with addresses, insert either 1 (if matches with salesdataA) or 2(if matches with salesdataB). The name of new column is Project_ID. How can I do this?

```
create table allsalesdata as
(select * from salesdataA
union all
select * from salesdataB)
order by 1 

select * from allsalesdata

ID                   Address                          Project_ID (requested)
1                    111 Obama Drive                           1
1                    111 New York Street                       2
2                    222 Clinton Drive                         1
2                    222 Vermont Road                          2
3                    333 Obama Street                          1
3                    333 Florida Drive                         2
4                    444 McCain Road                           1
4                    444 Georgia Lane                          2

select * from salesdataA:

ID                   Address
1                    111 Obama Drive
2                    222 Clinton Drive
3                    333 Obama Street
4                    444 McCain Road

select * from salesdataB:

ID                   Address
1                   111 New York Street
2                   222 Vermont Road
3                   333 Florida Drive
4                   444 Georgia Lane


update allsalesdata
CASE when sd.Address = pcr.Address then 1
else 2
end as Project_ID
left join allsatesdata sd on salesdataA pcr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in when you create the table:

```
create table allsalesdata as
    select a.*, 1 as project_id
    from salesdataA
    union all
    select b.*, 2
    from salesdataB b
    order by 1 ;
```